# How to configure Node Export to mass node export?

Tags: 7, importing-exporting

I'm trying out Node Export for mass node export, but it seems that I have to choose every node to export individually.

What if I want to export all nodes of a selected content type? Is there any way I can do this in Node Export, or I should find another module?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do it with [drush](https://drupal.org/project/drush):

```
$ drush help ne-export
Export nodes using Node export.

Arguments:
  nids : A list of space-separated node IDs to export.

Options:
  --file : The filename of the output file.  If supplied, the node code will be
exported to that file, otherwise it will export to stdout.
  --format : If supplied, node code will be output using a particular export
format, if available. (e.g. serialize)
  --status : Filter for 'status'; A boolean value (0 or 1) indicating whether
the node is published (visible to non-administrators).
  --promote : Filter for 'promote'; A boolean value (0 or 1) indicating whether
the node should be displayed on the front page.
  --sticky : Filter for 'sticky'; A boolean value (0 or 1) indicating whether
the node should be displayed at the top of lists in which it appears.
  --translate : Filter for 'translate'; A boolean value (0 or 1) indicating
whether the node translation needs to be updated.
  --language : Filter for 'language'; The language code (e.g. de or en-US) of
this node.
  --type : Filter for 'type'; The machine-readable name (e.g. story or page) of
the type of this node.
  --sql : Filter by SQL (EXPERIMENTAL); An SQL query string that returns nids
(e.g. "SELECT nid FROM nodes WHERE nid < 10").
  --code : Filter by PHP code (EXPERIMENTAL); PHP code that prints or returns,
an array or CSV string of nids (e.g. "custom_get_my_nids();"). Don't include PHP
tags.
```

For example,

```
drush ne-export --type=article --file=article.txt
```

will output all of the article nodes to article.txt in serialized format.  You can then use drush to import them:

```
$ drush help ne-import
Import nodes previously exported with Node export.

Arguments:

Options:
  --uid : User ID of user to save nodes as. If not given will use the user with
an ID of 1. You may specify 0 for the Anonymous user.
  --file : The filename of the input file.  If supplied, the node code will be
imported from that file, otherwise it will import to stdin.
```

For example:

`drush ne-import --uid=1 --file=article.txt`

*updated

Comment: Thanks, but is this suitable for large amount of nodes (> 1000) ?

Comment: In theory, yes, if you give PHP enough memory and set a pretty high execution time.  I think the last time I did this I had hundreds of nodes, maybe close to a thousand.

Comment: Thanks again. Here is more info https://drupal.org/node/1681584. I'll try Views Data Export too

Comment: It you are good at programming then you should try migrate.

Comment: where the result exported file stored on the harddisk when using Drush command ?

Comment: @AhmadZain The output is stored wherever you specify it to do.  The above command should store the file in the same place you ran the command from.

Comment: @mpdonadio How can I pass offset and limit in drush command for node export. I have 8 lakh of articles. I want to export all these articles. Exporting in single query gives me memory allocation issue. So I want to give some offset and limit then multiple people can export these articles in a short period. Can you please help me out.

Comment: @mpdonadio I added offset and limit as same as "$format".ie. $offset = drush_get_option('offset');  and $limit = drush_get_option('limit');    $query->range($offset, $limit);. And i used drush command drush node-export-export --type=aerticle --file=article.xml --format=xml --status=1 --offset=0 --limit=3       But it is not working...Unknown options: --offset, --limit.

Answer (score 5):

You could go to the list of all content in Drupal's admin pages ( /admin/content in D7), then filter by content type, then select all, then select 'Node export' from the dropdown menu

Comment: Yes!  This is the answer I have been looking for.  This is a lot easier than having to install and configure Views Bulk Operations (VBO).  For such a simple solution, it was really hard to find.

Comment: That only exports the current page of content of that type, not ALL the content of type.

Comment: `then select 'Node export' from the dropdown menu` what menu?

Comment: it may answer that last question. I also was not seeing this till i disabled the admin_views_node View which had been turned on for that site, and cleared caches. now in the Update Options dropdown at admin/content, i see an option to 'node export'.  Alternatively, if i have that View enabled, I can edit it, select the Bulk Operations field and add the 'node export' operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Node export](https://drupal.org/project/node%5fexport) module for above mentioned purpose.
It says:

> It allows users to export nodes and then import it into
>   another Drupal installation, or on the same site. Using this module
>   you can save yourself a lot of time setting up new websites that have
>   similar nodes to websites you've already made, migrating nodes to new
>   Drupal versions, or between development/staging/production sites.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you in dividing the results. Simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Run this script in Drupal root app directory!
# Requirements: drush command tool installed with ne-export command (you need Node Export module installed in Drupal)

maxRows=100
startFrom=0
for i in {0..17}
do
  startFrom=$(( (i)*100 ))
  echo "SELECT nid FROM node where node.type='noticia' limit $startFrom,$maxRows" # just for debugging
  drush ne-export  --file="nodes-exported/nodes-exported-$i.json" --format='json' --sql="SELECT nid FROM node where node.type='noticia' limit $startFrom,$maxRows" # of course set your own SQL here
done

exit 0
```